# Publishing actions on google failed with unclear message

Tags: actions-on-google

Every time I try to publish my actions on google for alpha release it denies the request with this unclear error message:

> For en: Your sample invocations are structured incorrectly. Make sure they all start with a trigger phrase, include either your app name or pronunciation, and successfully invoke your app.

My trigger phrases all passes the invocation page rules and it works fine in the simulator. this is my invocation phrase
*Talk to Doctor Electronics*

Any one has a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like it is talking about the *sample invocations* configuration, which is in the *Directory information* page of the console for your Action under the *Details* section. Make sure these phrases are correctly structured and make sense for your action.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked. it is really confusing that the invocation settings is spread in many places.